# How to use variables in sql query in python

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to make a banking system and its one of the functions I've defined

```
def fetch(temp_pass,temp_accno):
    cur.execute("SELECT  id,name,acc_no,ph_no,address,email,balance from accounts where id = %s and acc_no = %s",(temp_pass,temp_accno,))
    row = cur.fetchall();
    return row
```

**This is the error I get**

```
*\Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Accounting.py", line 126, in <module>
    deposit()
  File "Accounting.py", line 79, in deposit
    fetch(temp_pass,temp_accno)
  File "Accounting.py", line 8, in fetch
    cur.execute("SELECT  id,name,acc_no,ph_no,address,email,balance from accounts where id = %s and acc_no = %s",(temp_pass,temp_accno,))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character = integer
LINE 1: ...h_no,address,email,balance from accounts where id = 1234 and...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.*
```

Can someone please tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: is temp_pass,temp_accno are int values or string values, also remove extra comma `,` after `temp_pass,temp_accno,` should be `temp_pass,temp_accno`

Comment: They are int values

Comment: did you tried by removing extra comma?

Comment: also, try this `cur.execute("SELECT id,name,acc_no,ph_no,address,email,balance from accounts where id = " + temp_pass + " and acc_no = " + temp_accno)`

Comment: That didnt work but I got it correct now

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.execute('''SELECT id, name, acc_no, ph_no,address, email,balance
               FROM accounts
               WHERE id = %s and acc_no = %s''',
            (str(temp_pass), str(temp_accno)));
```